# Should I season a Teflon-coated stainless steel frying pan

Tags: pan, frying-pan, seasoning-pans

I am not sure if I am allowed to say the brand & model, but here is the spec

- Can also be used in the oven since it is made entirely of metal.
- Thick base with one layer of aluminium between two layers of stainless steel. Gives an even and energy-efficient heat, which reduces the risk of food burning and sticking.
- Made of stainless steel, which makes the pan durable and easy to clean.
- Treated with Teflon® Platinum plus, a very hardwearing non-stick coating that makes the pan suitable for everyday use.
- The exterior is made of brushed steel which means that stains do not show as much as on a high-gloss surface.

Should I season it?

Related question: [What's the best way to season a cast iron skillet?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/641/whats-the-best-way-to-season-a-cast-iron-skillet)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to season a stainless steel saute pan?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10500/do-i-need-to-season-a-stainless-steel-saute-pan)

Comment: You can say the brand and model. Though I don't think it really matters here.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The other question is about stainless, this question asks about Teflon-coated.

Answer (score 8):

No. Neither plain stainless steel nor non-stick pans (which yours is as it's coated with Teflon) need to be seasoned. Not only is seasoning unnecessary, but it will only cause your pan to look dirty. It would do no good at all.

Seasoning is all about preventing rust and sealing "pores", making the surface more resistant to sticking. Neither of those things are an issue with stainless steel or Teflon, and it's unlikely that the seasoning would even stick to your pan. On your pan you can even use soap!

Some people (a distinct minority) do season stainless steel ([Do I need to season a stainless steel saute pan?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10500/do-i-need-to-season-a-stainless-steel-saute-pan)), but absolutely don't try to season Teflon.

**EDIT:** It is often recommended use a paper towel to wipe a small amount of oil on Teflon before use. Apparently some people do call that "seasoning", but it bears no resemblance to the seasoning of cast-iron. [NY Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/12/18/your-money/18shortcuts.html?_r=2&)

Answer (score 1):

**Absolutely not**

A non-stick pans surface will be ruined when any oil becomes polymerised onto it. The whole idea of a non-stick pan is that it's surface is non-stick to food. Permanently layering it with anything else will make it less non-stick

Only use non-stick pans for low to medium heat cooking, and use no, or very little oil in them. Be very gentle with the surface so as not to scratch it, as the scratches eventually make it sticky again

Most manufacturers of non-stick pans recommend gentle hand washing with soap from new, and then removal of excess oil from the pan with a plain paper towel while still warm. Never hard washing or scrubbing

If oil does become polymerised onto the surface, sometimes you can recover them by using 3M style green polyester scourers with liquid soap to gently remove the hardened oil, if done carefully it will not overly scratch the non-stick coating

Seasoning is for plain metal pans, not for coated, glass, or ceramic