# Non-stick spray substitute

Tags: butter, non-stick

What would be good substitutes for non-stick spray? I've heard butter or vegetable oil. Would something like Crisco work?

Comment: curious here.. why are you looking for a substitute? save money or avoiding aerosols or..?

Comment: I had run out of non-stick spray and didn't want to run to the store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crisco is grease and would work just like oil or butter. Bacon fat will work as well.

Answer (score 7):

Non-stick spray is mostly canola oil plus some water and an emulsifier. So canola oil would work well as would most vegetable oils.

To get an application closer to non-stick spray you can pour some on a paper towel and rub it on your cooking surface. You can also buy misters that are made especially for this purpose.

Crisco is mostly soy bean oil and palm oil. It will technically work well, but personally I find the flavor of palm oil to be a little stronger and not as appetizing as other vegetable oils.

Comment: [Misto](http://www.amazon.com/misto/dp/B00004SPZV) is quite inexpensive; saves you money - instead of buying aerosol cans. Also check out [this](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2690) post about adding oil to a *not* non-stick pan after it heats up a bit, indicating it will spread out better.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much any oil or liquid fat (like melted butter) will do. The thing you want is to match the burn points of your oils. The higher the heat the more careful you need to be. So if it calls for canola spray, melted butter may not be right because it can burn at much lower temperatures. If in doubt, stick with a high-heat oil like canola or safflower.

If applying it is a problem where spraying would help, using a brush will usually do almost as well.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer safflower or sunflower oil for baking, olive oil for pan cooking.

Answer (score -1):

a little canola/vegetable oil or take a stick of butter and rub it on the pan.

Answer (score -3):

Mineral oil by towel or sprayer.

Comment: Mineral oil is a laxative for short-term use only. Don't cook with it.