# Place oil on cold or hot skillet?

Tags: oil, sauteing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you heat the pan first, then add oil? Or put the oil in and heat up with the pan?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2690/do-you-heat-the-pan-first-then-add-oil-or-put-the-oil-in-and-heat-up-with-the-p)

When sauteing food with oil, how do the following two sequences differ in the final taste of the food?

**A**

1. Place oil in skillet.
2. Turn on stove and wait for oil to heat up.
3. Place food in skillet.

**B**

1. Turn on stove and wait until it's hot.
2. Place oil in skillet. Oil should heat up in a few seconds.
3. Place food in skillet.

Comment: Although the earlier question doesn't really go into the taste difference between the two methods.

Comment: I think that the taste difference is exactly what is meant by "degrading the oil" which a number of the answers referenced.

Comment: While the question may be subtly different, I think that the answers in the linked question already suitably answer this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version B runs the risk of overheating the pan and damaging the coatings on it. I've always been told to put oil in the pan before heating for that reason - nothing to do with taste. I'd seriously doubt you could detect any difference in taste.

Comment: A Sauté doesn't have a coating. I always use method two as the oil will not burn if you leave the pan unattended. I don't think, as you do, that there will be any difference in taste.

Comment: A Saute might have a coating. However, people would have read "saute" as a verb and in that case it's a process done in whatever pan is to hand in your normal house - meaning a normal frying pan which probably does have a coating.